# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in...

Tags: php, curl

```
<?php

    $list($first,$second) = explode('<br>',curl_multi_getcontent ($curl_arr[$i]));
      echo $first;
      echo "<br>";
      echo $second;
      echo "<br>";
      echo udate('H:i:s:u');
      echo "<br><br>";
      usleep(100000);
      unset $first, $second;
?>
```

Error occurs on the first line

```
$list($first,$second) = explode('<br>',curl_multi_getcontent ($curl_arr[$i]));
```

Any reason why?

`$curl_arr[$i]` isn't empty once `curl_multi_getcontent` has been run on it.

Comment: You're aware there's a dollar symbol in front of the list function?

Comment: What is the content of $curls_arr[$i] ?

Comment: @middaparka: didn't notice until @BoltClock pointed it out. All fixed :) Thanks. @Eineki: All fixed, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list()` does not have a `$` in front of it.

```
list($first,$second) = explode('<br>',curl_multi_getcontent ($curl_arr[$i]));
```

If you add a `$` you are attempting to assign the return value of the `explode()` function into a (variable) function call, and that's how you get such an error. In other words, PHP thinks you're trying to do this, which makes no sense:

```
func1($params) = func2($params)
```

Using `list()` this way works because it's a language construct rather than a traditional function call. More about it in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php).

---

And I believe `unset()` requires parentheses (coincidentally, just like `list()`:

```
unset($first, $second);
```

Comment: Thanks! Now getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting '(' in..." which occurs at the final line..

Comment: should be unset ($first,$second)?

Comment: Excellent! Didn't see it before I posted. Thank you! :)